# Sitecore: syntax for sc:item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I want to create something like this

```
<xsl:variable name="content" select="sc:item('{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}',.)" />
```

But the id will be determined after user have selected some items. So what is the correct syntax to do it?

I have tried several:

```
<xsl:variable name="content"><xsl:value-of select="bla bla bla" /> </xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="content" select="sc:item(&lt;value-of select="bla bla bla" &gt;,.)" />
```

but no luck of getting it right.

Comment: What exactly is the user selecting, I presume this is from the website,  not from within the CMS interface? Something like a radio button or a select list? I'm sure someone will know how, personally I would just use an ascx and use easy C# code...

Comment: @jammykam: do you have any reference to do this in ascx and c# code?

Comment: What kind of field are you using to let the user select some items?

Comment: @MartijnvanderPut : actually the field return the id of the selected item. Thats all I know, then based on the id, I have to find the item somewhere in the content tree using the return id.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but in your XSL you need to get the ID or path of the item(s) you are working with to pass to the sc:item function.
You could use for example something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="content" select="sc:item($sc_currentitem/@id,.)" />
```

or you could use a list of items and loop through them like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$itemList/item">
  <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

EDIT:

if you want to get the selected items from a Treelist, you can select multiple items and the ID's are concatenated with a pipe character. You can use code like this to read the itemIDs and get the corresponding items:

```
<xsl:for-each select="sc:Split('FieldName',$sc_currentitem)">
   <xsl:variable name="item" select="sc:item(text(), $sc_currentitem)" />
   <xsl:value-of select="$item/@name" /><br />      
</xsl:for-each>
```

This part only displays the name of the item but of course you can do whatever you want with it.

If this still doesn't work, try outputting some values to the screen like the ID of the selected items by using `<xsl:value-of select="@id" />` inside the for-each.

Comment: Actually I want to compare 2 ids.
First, I need to find the item (in treeview, raw value) selected by user.
Then, I want to search the item in content tree using the raw value.

Comment: When you say user, do you mean content editor or anonymous user of the website, it's not clear to me (but Martijn's answer will do the first)

Comment: @MartijnvanderPut: The item selected is from the content editor. The selected item will an ID {110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}.  Then I have to use this ID to search for the exact item.
But I managed to do it in C#, just wondering how can I perform in xslt.